# Why I'm getting Validation failed (numeric string is expected)

Tags: nestjs, prisma

I have this code

```js
@Get()
  @ApiQuery({
    name: "code",
    type: String,
    required: false,
  })
  @ApiQuery({
    name: "id",
    type: Number,
    required: false,
  })
  async read(
    @Query("entity") entity: string,
    @Query("code") code: string,
    @Query("id", ParseIntPipe) id: number
  ): Promise<Q> {
    return this.service.readAsync({ where: { codigo: code, id: id } });
  }
```

Why I'm getting `Validation failed (numeric string is expected)` when I request to `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/endpoint?entity=a&code=b`

I know is related with id param, but I don't know how to solve this.

I want to be able to use code or id params according my needs.

If I request to `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/endpoint?entity=a&code=b&id=1` or `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/endpoint?entity=a&id=1` all is fine.

Comment: I get the error when I request to http://localhost:3000/api/v1/endpoint?entity=a&code=b

Answer (score 2):

`ParserIntPipe` doesn't work on optional parameters, from its [source code](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/common/pipes/parse-int.pipe.ts), you can see

```js
  async transform(value: string, metadata: ArgumentMetadata): Promise<number> {
    if (!this.isNumeric(value)) {
      throw this.exceptionFactory(
        'Validation failed (numeric string is expected)',
      );
    }
    return parseInt(value, 10);
  }

  /**
   * @returns `true` if `value` is a valid integer number
   */
  protected isNumeric(value: string): boolean {
    return (
      ['string', 'number'].includes(typeof value) &&
      /^-?\d+$/.test(value) &&
      isFinite(value as any)
    );
  }
```

As per Micael Levi answer, you either provide a default value using `DefaultValuePipe` in case it was missing, or you build your own custom pipe that pass parameter undefined value

Answer (score 1):

here `@Query("id", ParseIntPipe) id: number` you're saying that the query parameter `id` is required and must be an integer.

Thus, if you do `GET /endpoint?entity=a&code=b`, it will reply with bad request as there's no `id` parameter.

You can use the [`DefaultValuePipe`](https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes#providing-defaults) pipe if `id` should be optional and will have a fallback value.

If you don't want any default value, then you'll need to write your own pipe (that could `extends ParseIntPipe`). Or you could use the builtin one `ValidationPipe` with `class-validator` decorators.